# Defining a model name based on list of serial numbers and X in a certain cell

Tags: excel, serialization

I have a table of 3 columns. Each Column represents a model of an aircraft (3 different model numbers). The lists contains the serial numbers of aircraft for each specific model. When I enter X in a cell under the model designation on an order form and add a serial number in another cell I need the model designation to auto fill the correct model designation.

I'm using a table as serial numbers are not in consecutive order.

X in A7 and number in E4 will auto-enter model designation in A6 based on table on another worksheet listing 3 columns of serial numbers.

Example of Model and serial numbers

```
F2EX    F2LX    F2S
28       57     701
29       82     & subsequent
30       83 
31      101
```

I've been trying to do this using `VLOOKUP` but can't figure out how to make a cell look at table based on serial number listed or how to make it auto-fill the model number.

Comment: I see what I copied as table example from Excel did not keep formatting. F2EX model is SN 28,29,30,31. F2LX model is SN 57,82,83,101, F2S model is SN 701 and higher or subsequent.

Comment: Couldn't do it with what you provided. I was able to make it work using VLookup.   =IF(AND(A7="X"),VLOOKUP(E4,'Serial Number'!A2:B477,2,0),"F2Ey II")

Answer (score -1):

Pnuts was not able to get what you provided to work. I was finally able to make a VLOOKUP that worked. 
 =IF(AND(A7="X"),VLOOKUP(E4,'Serial Number'!A2:B477,2,0),"F2Ey II")